# Send data from ajax to c# server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I've created a dictionary on cliend side and want to send it on sever side. In my script, dictionary is created correctly, but I'm not sure abount my ajax code.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var sendList = new Array();
        var elems = $(".elemValue");
        $.each(elems, function (key, value) {
            if (value.attributes.elemName.nodeValue != "PhotoImg") {
                sendList[value.attributes.elemName.nodeValue] = value.attributes.value.nodeValue;
            }
        });

        var data = JSON.stringify({dict : sendList});

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dataloader.aspx/GetData",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result){
                alert(result.d);
            }
        });
        });
```

On server side I wrote

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetData(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> serverDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        serverDict = dict;
        string result = "";
        foreach (var value in dict)
        {
            result += "The key is:" + value.Key + "The value is:" + value.Value;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Where are my mistakes, and how can I fix them? Help, please=)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, any error. Just script is not working at all. Even VS debugger is not called.

Comment: So the script isn't making the AJAX request?

Comment: @Spencer Ruport, no, it isn't.

Comment: I changed script like this:


'$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dataloader.aspx/GetData",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: alert("It's alive!!")
            
        });'
And it's working: success event is performed, but server side is not.

Comment: I find out why error is occuring. Just to change "GET" to "POST"))) Wood for trees=)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to create a Dictionary from JSON. At least not without a lot of work. I would try changing it from a `Dictionary` to a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` and see if it deserializes for you.

Reference for [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

Once you've done that if you still need the Dictionary you can convert it fairly easily.

```
var Dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(var KVP in List) Dictionary.Add(KVP.Key, KVP.Value);
```

Comment: Problem is in ajax script, because it fails. Thanks for this answer, but first of all I need to make this code works.=)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

1. You need to allow GET verb explicitly:

   ```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
   ```
2. You are returning plain text from the server, which means that this line:

   ```
   dataType: "json"
   ```

   won't let jQuery parse the response correctly. You should either remove this line, or build response in JSON format.